# Scatter plot Script Help to visualize statistically significant genes with their corresponding Z-scores

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

So I have a dataset of unique genes under the column name "ï..Gene" for the x-xis and their respective Z-scores under the column name "UbZScore" for the y-axis.

I've run this script to generate a scatter plot of the genes with their corresponding Z-score values. My intended scatter plot aims to color the genes with a Z-score of at least 1.96 or less than -1.96, with the genes satisfying the condition displaying their gene name next to the dot on the graph. Also I was wondering what alterations are needed for my code for the colors of "TRUE" or "FALSE" to be different than what the script automatically generates and how to rename the "TRUE" and "FALSE" to something else too. I've attached the generated graph from the script as well.

```
    ggplot(MasterScreen, mapping=aes(x = ï..Gene, y = UbZscore)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = {UbZscore >= 1.96 | UbZscore<= -1.96})) +
      labs(
        x = "Genes",
        y = "Z-Score of Ubiquitin Colocalization",
        color = "Statistical Significance",
        title = "Significant Genes in Ubiquitin Colocalization")
```

[Photo of Dataset I'm working with for formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZlST.jpg)
[Photo of the scatterplot generated from the code above with the significant genes highlighted in red with the logical operator used from UbZscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Il4.png)

Update 7/29: I attached a photo of the dataset I'm working with to see if the way it's set up is affecting any suggested codes. Additionally, I see that the graph photo did not attach properly as well, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

One way to color data points according to their values is to have multiple filtered dataframes.

It would be better if you could provide some subset of your dataframe for us to try and solve it.
But either way here goes my suggestion.

First you filter your dataframe by the z-score.

```
library(dplyr)

    MasterScreenHigh <- MasterScreen %>%
        filter(UbZscore > 1.96)

    MasterScreenInner <- MasterScreen %>%
        filter(UbZscore <= 1.96 && UbZscore >= -1.96)

    MasterScreenLow <- MasterScreen %>%
        filter(UbZscore < -1.96)
```

and later use the three datasets to plot different aesthetics to the datapoints, like this:

```
ggplot(MasterScreenInner, aes(x = ï..Gene, y = UbZscore, col = 'red')) +
          geom_point(size = 3) +
          geom_point(data=MasterScreenLow, aes(x = ï..Gene, y = UbZscore), size=3, color='green') +
          geom_text(data = MasterScreenLow, aes(label='textYouWant'),hjust=0, vjust=0, color='black') +
          geom_point(data = MasterScreenHigh, aes(x = ï..Gene, y = UbZscore), size=3, color='blue') +
          geom_text(data = MasterScreenHigh, aes(label='textYouWant'),hjust=0, vjust=0, color='black') +
          theme(text = element_text(size=20),
              axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
          labs(title = 'PlotTitle', x='Genes', y='Z-Score of Ubiquitin Colocalization')
```

I'm not sure this will work perfctly since I don't have any data to try. But this way is possible. I've done it many times.

Comment: Making several dataframes is definitely not the best way to do this, why not just create a new variable and colour by that?

Comment: That is actually a nice suggestion, creating a new column based on the threshold values. Thanks for the input

Comment: Howdy Omar, I just updated the question with a screenshot of the dataset format, but thank you for the warm welcome. Just started a research project and it required me to crunch 900 genes for visualization so I jumped on the R coding train earlier this month and boy, it's something to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new variable based on your threshold, and colour by that variable. If you use dplyr, you can use `case_when` as a vectorized if-statement. For example, using mtcars, we can create a `col` variable that is 'red' when mpg < 20 and 'green' when mpg >= 20 (obviously, you modify this for your statistic). You can also just pass `label` to your ggplot's `aes` call, and add `geom_text`, to get the labels on the actual plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
    mutate(
        # add variable of labels
        name = row.names(.),
        # add colour variable
        col = case_when(
            mpg < 20 ~ 'red',
            mpg >= 20 ~ 'green')) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, color = col, label = name)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi your suggestion was successful in generating names for the genes but I want to know if there was a script you may suggest in removing the names from a range of values based on the y-axis. Thank you so much for the previous script too!

Comment: Hi. If the answer successfully addressed your question, please mark it as accepted. You should make a new post with the new question. Feel free to let me know when you post it.